# EDITED: spreading data based on column match

Tags: r

I have an empty data frame I am trying to populate.

Df1 looks like this:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 important_col
1   82  193  104   86           120
2   85   68  116   63           100
3   78  145   10  132            28
4  121  158  103   15           109
5   48  175  168  190           151
6   91  136  156  180           155
```

Df2 looks like this:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

A data frame full of `0`'s.

I combine the data frames to make `df_fin`.

What I am trying to do now is something similar to a dummy variable approach… I have the column in `important_col`. What I am trying to do is `spread` this column out, so if `important_col` = `28` then put a `1` in column `28`.

How can I go about creating this?

EDIT: I added a comment to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. I paste it here also.

> Say that the important_col is countries, then the column names would
>   be all the countries in the world. That is in this example all of the
>   241 countries in the world. However the data I might have already
>   collected might only contain 200 of these countires. So
>   one_hot_encoding here would give me 200 columns but I am missing
>   potentially 41 countries. So if a new user from a country (not
>   currently in the data) comes to the data and inputs their country,
>   then it wouldn´t be recognised

Smaller example:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 important_col 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1    11   14    3   11             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     1    1   19   15             4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     3   17   10   10             6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4    13   10    8   17            10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5    18    5    3   18            19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6    11   10    9    5            17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7     5   11   18   16            17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8     5    8   13    8             6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9    10    1    7   16            12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10    4   17   17    3             4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Expected output:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 important_col 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1    11   14    3   11             1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2     1    1   19   15             4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     3   17   10   10             6 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4    13   10    8   17            10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5    18    5    3   18            19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
6    11   10    9    5            17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
7     5   11   18   16            17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
8     5    8   13    8             6 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9    10    1    7   16            12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10    4   17   17    3             4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The number of columns is greater than the number of potential entries into `important_col`. Using the `countries` example the columns would be all countries in the world and the `important_col` would consist of a subset of these countries.

Code to generate the above:

```
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(1:20, 10, rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df1) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "important_col")
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(20, sample(0:0, nrow(df1), rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df2) <- gsub("X", "", colnames(df2))
df_fin <- cbind(df1, df2)
df_fin
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: When you say "put a 1 in column 120", you mean in all the rows of that column, or what?

Comment: Line 3 : `df2 <- ` has a typo with `nrow(df2)` ; should be `nrow(df1)`, please update it

Comment: Thanks I corrected that error. Regarding the"put a 1 in column 120" - I Will eventually have a sparse matrix, so if `120` occured in `important_col` then put a 1 only in column `120` of that row.

Comment: I have aded a small example of the output expected. Hopefully its a Little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve the problem:

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(1:20, 10, rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df1) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "important_col")
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(20, sample(0:0, nrow(df1), rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df2) <- gsub("X", "", colnames(df2))
df_fin <- cbind(df1, df2)
```

Result:

```
vecp <- colnames(df2)

imp_col <- df1$important_col

m <- matrix(vecp, byrow = TRUE, nrow = length(imp_col), ncol = length(vecp))

d <- ifelse(m == imp_col, 1, 0)

df_fin <- cbind(df1, d)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 important_col 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1     6   20   18   20             3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2    16   10   14   19             9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3     9   14   13   14             9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4    18   12   20   16             8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5    19    3   14    1             4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6     1   18   15   10             3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7    11    5   11   16             5 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8    18    1   12    5            10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9    12    7    6    7             6 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10   10   20    3    5            18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is `one hot encoding` which you can easily achieve using `model.matrix`

Below example should take you to the right direction:

```
df <- data.frame(important_col = as.factor(c(1:3)))
df

  important_col
1             1
2             2
3             3

as.data.frame(model.matrix(~.-1, df))
  important_col1 important_col2 important_col3
1              1              0              0
2              0              1              0
3              0              0              1
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I Don´t think I am exactly trying to do `one_hot_encoding` or `dummy_variables`. Since the `unique(colnames())` is larger than the `unique(important_col)` items.

Comment: Say that the `important_col` is countries, then the column names would be all the countries in the world. That is in this example all of the 241 countries in the world. However the data I might have already collected might only contain 200 of these countires. So `one_hot_encoding` here would give me 200 columns but I am missing potentially 41 countries. So if a new user from a country (not currently in the data) comes to the data and inputs their country, then it wouldn´t be recognised.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sonny mentioned, model.matrix() should do the job. One potential problem is that you have to add back columns that did not show up in your important_col like the following case:

```
df <- data.frame(important_col = as.factor(c(1:3, 5)))
df
  important_col
1             1
2             2
3             3
4             5
as.data.frame(model.matrix(~.-1, df))
  important_col1 important_col2 important_col3 important_col5
1              1              0              0              0
2              0              1              0              0
3              0              0              1              0
4              0              0              0              1
```

Col4 is missing in the second df, because the important_col does not include value 4. You have to add back the col 4 if you need it for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is a similar method to what @Sonny suggested. I perhaps didn`t make myself totally clear. I added a small example to try and illustrate what I am trying to achieve below his response. I will edit my question slightly also.